# how can I create java library where it's implementation is hidden?

Tags: java, android, static-libraries

I'm developing an android app and I want to make one of the app's classes (Java class) a library. 
I've managed to create a library from that class, but when I use it in another project I can see the all the class's implementation (I'm not able to change it, but I can see all the code).

If I want to distribute this library, what is the best way to hide the implementation?

Comment: One option is to use a web service that you hide the implementation of, then you distribute a public REST client. This is how the Twitter, Facebook, Google, etc libraries exist.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure it's the right solution for me, I want to share the use to a specific developer and not public. does it suit my situation?

Comment: By "public" I don't mean expose to the whole world, I only mean you're exposing a black box of functions to external systems via a network interface. You're in full control of who you give access to, how much functionality you expose, and no one can see the internals of the server code

Comment: OK, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and trying will only annoy your users and provide a false sense of security. If your library is only secure if its implementation is secret, you designed it wrong and need to redo it.

Comment: Not trying to annoy any users :) the reason I need to hide the implementation is that I need to share it with a different company. If I designed it wrong, what is the right way?

Comment: I don't understand why sharing it with a different company means that you need to hide it.

Comment: I don't understand how is your answers helpful, I didn't ask "should I hide it", I need to resolve something else.
It's like I'll ask how to grow oranges and you'll answer - "why don't you buy some apples?"